# sentry: setUserContext in nodejs with raven-node?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sentry, raven

I've tried to get the setUserContext function with raven-node in my nodejs app, but I cannot find how to set the user context. Has anyone made it work?

I was able to make it work in the client-side, with "Raven.setUserContext" but not in the nodejs backend :(

Comment: hi Diego, if you're using getsentry.com, you can file a ticket at support@getsentry.com and we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User context isn't implemented in raven-node: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-node/issues/134

I'm a contributor to the project, and it's my number one priority to have this done shortly – should be a matter of days.

**Edit** – we just published [raven-node 0.10.0](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-node/releases/tag/0.10.0) which adds `setUserContext`.

Comment: Great, that's a very good news (the ETA). thanks a lot, I'll keep an eye on it.